# Accessing resources from a jar

Tags: java, jar, embedded-resource

I've created a jar, which contains some Scala code, and also included some resources in a bin directory - in this case they're executables. These are dependencies of the scala application, which knows to look for them in the bin directory when running from source (rather than the jar).

My question is, how do I go about extracting my executables when the jar is run? I've found lots of answers talking about how to extract a particular file, but I'd like to extract the whole directory, since in the general case there could be dozens of files, which I'd prefer not to name individually.

Comment: Use a zip file resource. With a ZipOutputStream you can then extract all.

Comment: Unzipping EXE files on the fly will most likely give you a _lot_ of support calls.  Why do you need them?

Comment: The Scala application calls off to some native C++ applications, that's why I need them. I'll use ZipOutputStream or something to extract to the machine's temporary directory, and run from there.

Answer (score 1):

Please don't do this. You will never know if the directory containing the jar file is writeable by the current executing user.

Use an installer to perform such tasks.